# Arc Length: Difficulty With The Integral

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus

The question is to find the arc length of a portion of a function.

$$y=\frac{3}{2}x^{2/3}\quad \text{ on }\, [1,8]$$

I couldn't quite figure out how to evaluate the integral, so I appealed to the solution manual for aid.
\begin{align*}
y & = \frac{3}{2}x^{2/3}\\
y' & = \frac{1}{x^{1/3}}, \quad 1 \le x \le 8\\
s & = \int_1^8 \sqrt{1+ \left ( \frac{1}{x^{1/3}}\right ) ^2}\, dx\\
& = \int_1^8 \sqrt{\frac{x^{2/3}+1}{x^{2/3}}} \, dx\\
& = \frac{3}{2} \int_1^8 \sqrt{x^{2/3}+1}\left ( \frac{2}{3x^{1/3}}\right )\, dx\\
& = \frac{3}{2}\left [ \frac{2}{3}(x^{2/3}+1)^{3/2} \right ]_1^8\\
 & = 5 \sqrt{5} - 2 \sqrt{2} \approx 8.352
\end{align*}

I don't quite understand what they did in the 5th step. Could someone perhaps elucidate it for me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This makes the integral computable, and it is just rewriting the integrand from step 4.  We see the constants multiply to $1$ (the constant outside the integral is $\frac{3}{2}$, the constant inside is $\frac{2}{3}$, and you can pull the constant out.  The only other thing remaining is the $x^{-\frac{1}{3}}$, which we get by simplifying 
$$\sqrt{\frac{1}{x^\frac{2}{3}}} \mbox{ to } \sqrt{x^\frac{-2}{3}}={x^{-\frac{2}{3}}}^\frac{1}{2}=x^\frac{-1}{3}$$
Combining this all together, we see 
$$
\sqrt{\frac{x^\frac{2}{3}+1}{x^\frac{2}{3}}}=\frac{3}{2}\sqrt{x^\frac{2}{3}+1}\frac{2}{3x^\frac{1}{3}}.
$$
I hope this clarifies that step for you.

Answer (score 2):

The expression in brackets is precisely what you need for the substitution $u=x^{2/3}+1$ to work.